# What is the opposite of “Allow” for undoing a terminal command

Tags: macos

I'm looking to undo a command that I have executed through ARD to allow access to non-admin users to make changes to NETWork PREF. As I now need to remove the access it seems that I'm not able to find the right "word" to execute the command.

```
/usr/bin/security authorizationdb write system.services.systemconfiguration.network allow
```

### All I need to know is what the opposite of "allow" is, as "deny" doesn't seem to work. Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks

No one asked but just found my way back to this post and I've realised that I can share what the solution is ...pretty simple actually.

```
/usr/bin/security authorizationdb write system.services.systemconfiguration.network "variable"
```

Simply replace the "**variable**" with one of the following, based on your requirements:

"authenticate-admin"
or
"authenticate"
or
"admin"
or
"authenticate-admin-30"

This should be valid for 10.14 and probably above

Comment: The manual describes `deny`. Perhaps reboot? https://ss64.com/osx/security-authorizedb.html

Comment: as i read those keys back out, i see:  
<dict>
 <key>allow-root</key>
 <true/>
 <key>authenticate-user</key>
 <true/>
can you